# Trouble with nodemon: The server keeps restarting everytime I make change in the file, without executing the code

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I am just getting started with node. I have installed the nodemon using the command `npm install -g nodemon` now whenever I start my server using `nodemon server.js` it starts fine but as I make some changes to the code it just keeps on restarting the server which doesn't execute the code in the file, so my progress is not saved.

```
Ansh@LAPTOP-7QQ43AM7 MINGW64 /f/files/atom/Web Development/my-express-server
$ nodemon server.js
[nodemon] 1.19.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server has started on port 3000
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
```

Instead of starting the server again after restarting, it just stays in the restarting process

Comment: Do you have some code for us to look at? Even if you just provide a snippet of code where you start listening on port 3000.

Comment: Can you try executing `nodemon index.js -V` (verbose mode) and update your post with what you're receiving?

Comment: @J.Stott
This is the code in the file server.js-
`const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", function(request, response){
response.send("The root page")});

app.get("/about",function(req, res){
  res.send("This is the about page");
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server has started on port 3000");
})`

Every time I save after adding a new subpage(ex - about), the server gets restarted but doesn't implement the changes.
When I run the page - `http://localhost:3000/about` The webpage displays - `Cannot GET /about`

Comment: @DavidR It's still not working, the code in the terminal says - 
`$ nodemon server.js -V
[nodemon] 1.19.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter rs or send SIGHUP to 15460 to restart
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting node server.js
[nodemon] forking
[nodemon] child pid: 12932
[nodemon] watching 3 files
Server has started on port 3000
[nodemon] files triggering change check: server.js
[nodemon] matched rule: **\*.*
[nodemon] changes after filters (before/after): 1/1
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] server.js`